# Need help with high current step up DC

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, high-current, step-down, step-up

I need to design external battery for my flash.

I have checked it works with 4-6v DC with ~6a current to charge the capacitor in 2-3 second.

I have 18650 battery planning to use in 1S configuration. And i need to boost the voltage from 3.7v to ~5-6v .

*MT3608* boost modules can provide only 1-2amp max
*XL6009* boost modues work with >3.5v so it wouldn't work.
*XL4015* step down modules is also not working .. short circuit protection getting triggered.

Is there any modules which can boost to ~5-6v from those 18650 battery and can provide peak current more than >5A for a short period of time.

Or any way to step down from 2S battery pack to ~5-6V with peak current >5A.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Suggest 2S buck.  This will be easier on your batteries and improve their longevity.